# Inserting text file input into a linked list

Tags: java, file-io, linked-list

Hey guys I am trying to read from a text file and store each name into a linked list node.  When I read in the text file it reads the line, which is a name.  I am trying to store each name into a linked list node.  When I call the insertBack method and print it out, it shows that there is nothing in the nodes.  Could anybody point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated?

Here is the fileIn class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

public class fileIn {
    String fname;

    public fileIn() {
        getFileName();
        readFileContents();
    }

    public void readFileContents()
    {
        boolean looping;
        DataInputStream in;
        String line;
        int j, len;
        char ch;

        /* Read input from file and process. */
        try {
            in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname));
            LinkedList l = new LinkedList();

            looping = true;
            while(looping) {
                /* Get a line of input from the file. */
                if (null == (line = in.readLine())) {
                    looping = false;
                    /* Close and free up system resource. */
                    in.close();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("line = "+line);
                    j = 0;
                    len = line.length();
                    for(j=0;j<len;j++){
                        System.out.println("line["+j+"] = "+line.charAt(j));
                    }
                }
                l.insertBack(line);
            } /* End while. */

        } /* End try. */

        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        } /* End catch. */
    }

    public void getFileName()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter file name please.");
        fname = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered "+fname);
    }

}
```

This is the LinkedListNode class:

```
public class LinkedListNode
{

    private String data;
    private LinkedListNode next;


    public LinkedListNode(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public LinkedListNode getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode n)
    {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

And finally the LinkedList class that has the main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedList {

    public LinkedListNode head;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        fileIn f = new fileIn();
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        System.out.println(l.showList());   
    }

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    public void insertBack(String data){
        if(head == null){
            head = new LinkedListNode(data);
        }else{
            LinkedListNode newNode = new LinkedListNode(data);
            LinkedListNode current = head;
            while(current.getNext() != null){
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(newNode);
        }       
    }

    public String showList(){
        int i = 0;
        String retStr = "List nodes:\n";
        LinkedListNode current = head;
        while(current != null){
            i++;
            retStr += "Node " + i + ": " + current.getData() + "\n";
            current = current.getNext();

        }

        return retStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing the read text printed out in your console from your debugging statements?

Comment: And I would recommend `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` rather than `DataInputStream`. `DataInputStream.readLine` is deprecated.

Comment: In the console I can see where it says line=Shawn (or any other name) ad then after that it shows each letter being stored into the array on line[j].  When it gets to my showList method it just shows List Nodes: with nothing else after it.

Comment: Ahh that is nice to know, I will try and change that while I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create the `LinkedList` in your `fileIn`.

But then you do not export it:

```
  fileIn f = new fileIn();
  LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
```

What you need is something like this:

```
  fileIn f = new fileIn();
  LinkedList l = f.readFileContents(String filename, new LinkedList());
```

Change the method to use the `LinkedList` you created and then populate it. So the `fileIn` class might look like something like this:

```
public class fileIn {
    ...
    public void readFileContents(String fileName, LinkedList) {
        // fill linked list
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @PaulDraper in `fileIn::readFileContents()` he creates and populates a `LinkedList` and then never exports it.

Comment: Would you reccomend that I rewrite it an export line to the LinkedList class and create the list there?  Or would it be just as efficient?

Comment: @Shawn I suggest you make a method that takes and returns a `LinkedList` such as `public void readFileContents(LinkedList list)`. Then call it `fileIn.readFileContents(new LinkedList())` or something like that is more flexible and also a bit clearer what you are doing. Also, like another comment stated, use a `BufferedReader` and not a `DataInputStream`. And get rid of that ugly for(,,,) loop. Just do a `while((line = br.readLine())!=null)` ... fill linkedList. Search or read some Java tutorials and you will figure it all.

Comment: You can do it many ways. Just make sure what you fill, `LinkedList`, is accessible. Do yourself a favour and visit 'Java Ranch' or the online Java tutorials. They will help you write clear effective code.